# How to disable sandbox access for BBEdit after initially setting up sandbox access?

Tags: permissions, bbedit

I installed BBEdit (version 14.6.1 (14D24, 64-bit Intel, sandboxed)) on MacOS 13 (Ventura). In the Application Settings, I allowed "Sandbox Access" - however, I then changed my mind, wanting to be prompted for the folders instead for now. (I know I can go back later to enable the "Sandbox Access" feature.)

However, now I can't find a way to *disable* the Sandbox Access feature.

There's no "disallow" button on the Application Settings page, and clicking the Restore Defaults button on that page had no effect on the Sandbox Access.

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling BBEdit; however, upon reinstallation, Sandbox Access remains "allowed".

[image: BBEdit Sandbox Access Enabled]

Upon searching, I found information on *why* BBEdit wants this access; however, nothing about disabling it.

What do I need to do to remove/disable the Sandbox Access permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted BareBones support: easy as a `defaults` command. This does reset *all* the preferences back to their defaults, though:

```
defaults delete com.barebones.bbedit
```

---

I noticed that when I deleted the app without performing the above command, the `defaults` retained the `com.barebones.bbedit` key containing the app settings. That's why my preferences remained upon reinstalling BBEdit.

Also associated folders remained in the `/Library` and `~/Library` system folders.

So, to completely remove the app (not part of my original question), I dragged the app to the Trash, ran the command above, and searched system files for and deleted the folders with `barebones` or `bbedit`.